# Inject custom serializer into Redis

Tags: .net, serialization, redis

I'm having a problem migrating our project from AppFabric over to Redis. I'm getting an exception saying that Redis cannot serialize the objects, so what I'm trying to do is inject a custom serializer into the RedisSessionStateProvider to serialize the objects into a compatible data type.

The Redis docs hint that custom serializers are possible, but I can't find further documentation as to how to do it. Is this the right way to solve my problem, or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Can you add the error details? It is strange that it was working with AppFabric and now when you switched to Redis it fails - because in both cases you should use Serializable objects, in order to send them over the wire. So normally you should just mark your classes with the Serializable attribute.

Comment: @LiviuCostea - Marking the objects as serializable isn't an option for us. Most of the objects that need to be cached are in dlls that we can't touch. We're trying to convert the objects into a serializable format (probably binary) before they get sent to the cache.

In essence, we are trying to bypass the Redis serializer and hook up our own instead.